# ABS with Subtraction returning strange value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Why is my ABS formula when combined with subtraction returning a strange value and not 0 when an operation actually should give 0

[image]

^ Formula

[image]

^ Resulting formatted for currency (green), and below it the value that is in the cell

Comment: `ROUND` the result.